# From JSP script call page only to create cookies and then redirect

Tags: jsp, cookies

I need to call a page with parameters (contained in the url) and wait for answer, because I need the called page to create cookies in the browser. Is it possible? I tried to call it like:

```
URL url = new URL("http://domain:8080/location/something?username=user");
   HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
   con.connect();
```

But It does not create any cookie. When I use the same link in browser it creates cookies with no problems.

Thank you all a lot in in advance,
Martin

Comment: You have to read the response from the server and store the cookie. The browser is of course doing that.

Comment: Well, I'm able to catch the response from server (in that I can see values I need to store = the part Set-Cookie), but can you please advice me how to store them in the script? Is there any build in method how to store them as cookies by the script?